# who holds the memtables and SSTables in cassandra, the nodes or the cluster?

Tags: cassandra, nodes

Each node will have different memtables and SSTables or the entire cluster has certain number of these tables? And, in write operation, first it is written to the commit log and then to memtables and sstables. Is this done by the node? If not, what is the role of node in the write operation as discussed in the picture mentioned below?
https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjEmYGCkovXAhXEMo8KHeLtD48QjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.guru99.com%2Fcassandra-architecture.html&psig=AOvVaw0rqVl6BG9vn0TefAPCEb5t&ust=1508999138916139

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you create a table in Cassandra , a memtable is created.
Thus a node may have many memtables.
A SStable is created when a flush is triggered.

See this http://abiasforaction.net/apache-cassandra-memtable-flush/

For the other question **(Write path)** 
The operations are carried by node itself and the coordinator node orchestrating it 
 
Whenever a data is inserted,it goes into the memtable and is *appended* in the commit log.Commit logs  are replayed when a node has gone down

So consider you have once again flushed the data after this new insertion ,you will see 2 set(generation) of SStables . Now your partition data exists in multiple SStables.
Note that SStables are immutable. Later on you may also want to read how compaction kicks in.
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsConfigureCompaction.html.

Comment: thank you so much abhishek raj, can you please clarify some more information on how search process happens and a particular key is identified from the memtables when a search process happens? Is it like the column keys are stored in memtables?

Comment: you may post it as a separate question .I may answer there. Comment section space  is insufficient .

Comment: yeah, as you said, I have posted it as another question.. can you please look on to it once and give me some clarity

Answer (score 0):

Each node has its own memtables and sstables. Of course, there might be a coordinator node that would fire the operation, read/write, but the node holding the data is the one that is actually executing it.

Also, a cluster is a bunch of nodes working together, but there is no "cluster" entity that coordinates everything.

In the picture mentioned, the node is one red dot, the data center is nodes 1-4 and 5-8, so we have to data centers and all of them are part of the same cluster.

There are some important things worth mentioning when configuring a cluster: the cluster name, the partitioner and the snitch. All these need to be the same for all nodes. Also, in a cluster, you will define seed nodes, but these don't need to be the same for all nodes, though is a good idea to be the same.